# Magento 2 checkout summary shipping check subtotal

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, shipping, totals

I want to change the Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/shipping.html file and add a specific line when the subtotal is below a specific value.

How can I achieve this? I already tried this, but that does not work:

```
        <!-- ko if: totals().subtotalAmount < 29.95 -->
        <span class="shipping-cost"><!-- ko i18n: '$ 5,95' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: totals().subtotalAmount > 29.95 -->
        <span class="shipping-free"><!-- ko i18n: 'Free' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do that.

```
        <!-- ko if: totals()['subtotal'] < 29.95 -->
        <span class="shipping-cost"><!-- ko i18n: '$ 5,95' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: totals()['subtotal'] > 29.95 -->
        <span class="shipping-free"><!-- ko i18n: 'Free' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the trick

Comment: you are welcome. maybe, if you want to show other variables, you can try this.
`<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(totals())"></div>`